# Scaladoc sourcepath and source files

Tags: scaladoc

This question is directed at Scaladoc for Scala 2.12.

`scaladoc -help` spews out a lot of lines, including these two:

```
Usage: scaladoc <options> <source files>

-sourcepath <path>                   Specify location(s) of source files.
```

However, no mention is made of the source file paths. I assumed they would need to be relative to the `-sourcepath` value if specified, but I don't see `-sourcepath` having any effect. For example, each the following invocations produce the same result:

```
scaladoc root/src/test/scala/EtherTest.scala
scaladoc -sourcepath root root/src/test/scala/EtherTest.scala
scaladoc -sourcepath $PWD/root root/src/test/scala/EtherTest.scala
```

This seems wrong. I would have expected that the sourcepath would act as a prefix to the Scala file path, like this:

```
scaladoc -sourcepath root src/test/scala/EtherTest.scala
```

Unfortunately, the above yields:

```
error: source file 'src/test/scala/EtherTest.scala' could not be found
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just try go into the src root path `src/test/scala`， that  `scaladoc` will find right path of your source code。

Full commands

`cd src/test/scala && scaladoc EtherTest.scala`